# Option to set multiple keys in redis for nonexistent keys?

Tags: redis

From documentation of `MSETNX`:

> Sets the given keys to their respective values. MSETNX will not perform any operation at all even if just a single key already exists.

I would like to perform an operation that would add keys which are not present in redis and skip those that are already present.

Is there any command that perform such action?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry if stating the obvious here, but `EVAL` / `EVALSHA` + a simple Lua script could easily and efficiently do the job.